# Pycharm Intellisense and PyQT4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pycharm

I am using Pycharm to build a PyQt4 app. The Pychram IntelliSense is not working inside the virtual environment. To get the PyQt4 system working in the virtualenv, I used [vext.pyqt4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vext.pyqt4). Also, I am using Python 3.5 if that makes any difference.

Is there any easy fix to get the IntelliSense working?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that PyCharm has context of PyQt, and that it is recognized as a library under PyCharm's project settings. This will enable the auto-complete. **Settings** > **Project** > **Project Interpreter**.

Comment: I have checked the Project Interpreter and the PyQt Module is not show but the vext.pyqt4 module is shown. Is there any way to force PyCharm to have context with PyQt. For the amount that I will be be using PyQt I might just leave the intellisense broken as the app does work.